# How to connect to Redis running in Docker container via CLI

Tags: python, redis

docker-compose

```
web:
  container_name: authserver
  restart: always
  build: ./authserver
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - redis:redis
  environment:
    DEBUG: 'true'

redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

docker inspect authserver_redis_1

```
    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03"
```

From the Python interpreter on my host machine (meaning from where I run docker-compose itself) I can play around with Redis and get/set values

```
client = redis.StrictRedis(host='172.17.0.3', port=6379, db=0)

client.set("key01", "value01")
print client.get("key01")
>>>>"value01"
```

The issue I'm having is that if I run redis-cli from the command line

```
redis-cli -h 172.17.0.3 -p 6379
```

on the same host machine (the same machine I'm interacting with the Python interpreter on) and then run HGETALL *, I expect to have key01 and value01 returned, but instead it returns

```
(empty list or set)
```

I had a hard time following both the redis-cli and python redis library docs, so I'm guessing I did some things wrong.

Comment: Try it without the -h 172.17.0.3 part...I did not need a host unless I was pushing it through a virtual environment to a web page. The port and db should be enough...also make sure the default is actually db=0 or it may be giving you the right answer...if you saved data to db=0 and are asking to return from a different one now. Redis comes with 16 database channels so you need to be sure you are requesting from the right one...

Answer (score 21):

```
ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

This forwards redis from the container to your host, so you should just be able to connect to localhost as if redis was running directly your machine. If this doesn't work, you can do more digging by running

```
docker ps
```

to get a list of running container IDs, and then

```
docker exec -it <redis container ID> redis-cli
```

to connect directly to your redis container and run redis-cli.